# linear algebra : to find relevant structure for 3 stage interaction

Tags: linear-algebra

A family has 10 members, of which all cannot interact with each other at all times. Obtain all possible ways in which their interaction (between two persons) can take place. Assuming that the interaction between them can take place in at most 3 stages, obtain the relevant structure for each stage and interpret.

Comment: Please provide more context, where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts? Have have you tried already? We know only see a question, without any context given.

Comment: In particular, what does this have to do with linear algebra, what exactly do you mean by different ways that an interaction between two people can take place, and what do you mean by "3 stages"?